# How to stop catching signal(Ctrl + c) exception in debug mode

Tags: c++

I'm implementing `std::signal` into my server application to shut it down safely.

```
void signal_handler(int signal)
{
    if (signal == SIGINT)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello.\n";
        exit(signal);
    }
}

void threadFunc()
{
    while (gLoop)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello..\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    std::thread thrd{ threadFunc };
    thrd.join();
}
```

This is an example code

It works fine when I run it as release mode..

But it stops when I press Ctrl+c in debug mode and of course notify me that exception occurred.

I just want it to ignore the exception and see what I've done something wrong in the terminating process (memory leaks, violation exception etc.)

Is there anyway that I can do for it?

Comment: What exception exactly? Since I don't see why it would have caused an exception in this case.

Comment: @Miigon It is visual studio exception. It's not like violation exception or access error. It just notify me that interrupt just happened! But I figured it out to disable it

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out just a second after I post this!
I can do it by just disabling *catch this exception next time* setting in the exception box.